# How to set Array of enums in UserDefaults swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

I have custom type of enum array and I want to store it in UserDefaults using swift4.

```
enum DataType : Int
{
   case cloud = 1, files = 2, googleDrive = 3, mega = 4, others = 5
}
//
let arrayOfData : [DataType] = [.cloud, .files, .mega]
```

I want to store this array in UserDefaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `DataType` conform to `Codable`. It's pretty easy, just add `Codable`

```
enum DataType : Int, Codable
{
    case cloud = 1, files, googleDrive, mega, others // the consecutive raw values are inferred
}

let arrayOfData : [DataType] = [.cloud, .files, .mega]
```

Now encode the array as JSON data and save it

```
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(arrayOfData)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "dataType")
```

And read it back accordingly

```
do {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "dataType") {
        let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([DataType].self, from: data)
    }
} catch { print(error)}
```

Comment: Good answer vadian, as usual, but I have question. Is there any reason why should I use JSON coders instead of property list coders or here isn’t any difference?

Comment: In this case JSON is the better choice because it has no overhead like the plist header and the tags. Property List In UserDefaults is only useful if the object contains types JSON doesn’t support (Date and Data).

Comment: This one is new I will try this and post here the solution.

Answer (score 4):

convert your `DataType` to `rawValue` first.

```
enum DataType : Int
{
    case cloud = 1, files = 2, googleDrive = 3, mega = 4, others = 5
}
//
let arrayOfData:[DataType] = [.cloud, .files, .mega]
let rawArrayOfData = arrayOfData.map { $0.rawValue }

UserDefaults.standard.setValue(rawArrayOfData, forKey: "hello")

guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "hello") as? [DataType.RawValue] else {
    return
}
let saved = data.map{ DataType(rawValue: $0)!}
print(saved)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the rawValues of `DataType`. Then, when retrieving the array from `UserDefaults`, map the values to `DataType`

```
enum DataType: Int {
    case cloud = 1
    case files = 2
    case googleDrive = 3
    case mega = 4
    case others = 5
}

let arrayOfData: [DataType] = [.cloud, .files, .mega]
let arrayKey = "enumArray"

UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayOfData.map { $0.rawValue }, forKey: "enumArray")

let rawArray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: arrayKey) as! [Int]

let dataTypeArray = rawArray.compactMap { DataType(rawValue: $0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save every type that confirms to `Codable` just like in the other answers.

```
enum DataType : Int, Codable
{
    case cloud = 1, files, googleDrive, mega, others // the consecutive raw values are inferred
}
```

In order to save an array of Codable Elements you can use an extension like this:

```
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
            print("Init from result: \(result)")
            self = result
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        print("Returning \(result)")
        return result
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
let arrayOfData : [DataType] = [.cloud, .files, .mega]

UserDefaults.standard(set: arrayOfData, forKey:"myArrayOfCodableEnums")
```

or:

```
@AppStorage("ArrayOfCodableEnums") var myArrayOfCodableEnums = [DataType]()
```